# Elixir: Keep asset information in rev-manifest.json when using different gulp flags

Tags: json, gulp

With `gulpUtil.env.sass` and `gulpUtil.env.js` I created two different flags to just run the Code I want. There is a flag `--sass`for the stylesheet and a flag `--js` for the scripts.

The problem is, everytime I run these flags with gulp, the rev-manifest.json gets overwritten with either the stylesheet information or the scripts information, but it never keeps both. How can I achieve that?

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulpUtil = require('gulp-util');

elixir(function(mix) {
    if(gulpUtil.env.sass) {
        mix.sass('../scss/main.scss'),
        mix.version([
            'public/css/main.css'
        ], 'public/');
    }
    if(gulpUtil.env.js) {
        mix.copy([
            'resources/assets/js/vendor/alertify.min.js',
            'resources/assets/js/create.test.js',
            'resources/assets/js/edit.test.js',
            'resources/assets/js/imgpreview.js',
            'resources/assets/js/whenAll.js',
        ], 'public/js')
        mix.version([
            'public/js/alertify.min.js',
            'public/js/create.test.js',
            'public/js/edit.test.js',
            'public/js/imgpreview.js',
            'public/js/whenAll.js'
        ], 'public/');
    }
});
```

See also: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/issues/10